# List Kubernetes api-server flags on GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I don't seem to be able to find a way to list all the flags the api server has set on GKE. Given I cannot SSH into the master nodes to check the process, as those are managed by Google, how do I find out i.e. what value is set for `--enable-admission-plugins=`?

I haven't found any apis in gcloud and kubectl that surfaced this information and even `kubectl cluster-info dump` doesn't have the flags.

Are those completely hidden from customers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you correctly said, what you are trying to do it is not possible at this moment because this configurations are managed by Google and there is no way to get them, from the user perspective. Actually there is a feature request about it that you can check [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/137539884).